# ReferenceError on Array item

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, variable-declaration

This should be a really simple script that changes the title of a column between 3 columns. I got it to work once, but now it's coming up with an error I don't understand:

> ReferenceError: "Today" is not defined. (line 10, file "Code")

Code is as follows:

```
function Progressions() {
  var workoutSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Workouts");

  var Increment = workoutSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 3).getValues();
  var newRoutine =[[]]

  if (Increment == [[Today,,]]){ 
    var newRoutine = [[ ,Today, ]]
    Increment.setValues(newRoutine);
  } else {
    if (Increment == [[,Today,]]){ 
      var newToday = [[,,Today]]
      Increment.setValues(newRoutine);
    } else {
      if (Increment == [[,,Today]]){ 
        var newToday = [[Today,,]]
        Increment.setValues(newRoutine);
      }
    }
  }
```

Obviously Today is not defined as that's just the content of the array.
I think this script should just change the content of the `newToday` array and then enter it into the `todayIncrement` range.

Any ideas how I can remove this error and achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why your code isn't working such as "Today" but also in your arrays with you call `.getValues();` the returned array will be something like `[["","Today",""]]`

You can't use `Increment.setValues(------);` as `increment` is an array an not a range object.

The if statement should be constructed

```
if(-----){

} else if (-----) {

} else {

}
```

This code does as you require:

```
function Progressions() {
    var workoutSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Workouts");
    var range = workoutSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 3);
    var increment = range.getValues();

    var newRoutine;
    var testValue = "Today";

    if (increment[0][0] == testValue) {
        newRoutine = [["", "Today", ""]];
    } else if (increment[0][1] == testValue) {
        newRoutine = [["", "", "Today"]];
    } else if (increment[0][2] == testValue) {
        newRoutine = [["Today", "", ""]];
    }
    range.setValues(newRoutine);
}
```

An alternate implementation of the if-else chain that is easier to extend (e.g. if you had 365 different workouts as columns, the above method needs 365 `if`-`else` checks), at the cost of needing more JavaScript knowledge to understand how it works:

```
function Progressions() {
  const workoutSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Workouts"),
      // 1 column per workout (here we have 3).
      headerRange = workoutSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 3),
      // Assume headers are in the range's first row.
      headers = headerRange.getValues()[0],
      newRoutine = [];

  // Use Array#indexOf to do all the nasty "if-else if" checking.
  const searchValue = "Today";
  const columnIndex = headers.indexOf(searchValue);
  if (columnIndex === -1)
    throw new Error("'" + searchValue + "' not found in headers ('" + headerRange.getA1Notation() + "').");

  // Set default header values (no Array#fill in Apps Script yet).
  headers.forEach(function (s) { newRoutine.push(""); });

  // Use addition and the modulus operator to increment and wrap.
  const newIndex = (columnIndex + 1) % newRoutine.length;
  newRoutine[newIndex] = searchValue;

  // Write the new header values.
  headerRange.setValues( [newRoutine] );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I doesn't seem to work though. The contents of the Increment array looks like this:  [[Today, , ]] and although if I put [["Today", ,]] the error goes away, but the if statement doesn't trigger.

Comment: I've tried it like this: if (Increment == [["Today"," "," "]]){ 
        Logger.log("If Triggered")  
       var newRoutine = [["" ,"Today","" ]]
       incrementRange.setValues(newRoutine); But the If still isn't triggering. although the Error has gone away

Comment: Please see above

Comment: Credit to @tehhowch for the second and much more flexible method.